# Bruteforce XOR cipher

Tags: c++, cryptography, xor, encryption, cracking

Is it possible to bruteforce the standard XOR cipher?

Knowing that this:

> *#(I@KI

is encoded with a XOR function

```
//
std::string CStringCoding::Xor( const std::string& strIn )
{
    std::string sOut = "";

    for(std::size_t loop = 0; loop < strIn.size(); loop++)
    {
        unsigned int iCharacter = static_cast<unsigned int>(strIn[loop] ^ sKey[loop % sKey.size()]);
        sOut += iCharacter;
    }

    return sOut;
}
```

Can i bruteforce that with a classic wordlist approach?

I was thinking of:

> Generate a Wordlist KEY
>
> XOR the **#(I@KI* with a KEY to DECIPHER it and obtain a STRING
>
> XOR the STRING with a KEY to CIPHER it
>
> Compare newly CIPHERED STRING with the INPUT CIPHERED STRING
>
> If they match, the KEY has been found

I didn't test it, just asking before i take action and spend too much time doing something that won't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are encrypting meaningful human-readable text, it is possible to break this [XOR cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) if the attacker will have:

1. ciphertext encoded with key reuse (e.g. loop % sKey.size() )
2. 2 ciphertexts encoded with the same key

[Frequency analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) can break both cases.

But it is fine to xor plaintext with truly random key of the same length as message. It will be unbreakable cipher: [One-Time Pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)

> OTP is immune even to brute-force attacks.Trying all keys simply
>   yields all plaintexts, all equally likely to be the actual plaintext

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by an "XOR cipher"?  As @varren has said, the One Time Pad is unbreakable.  However, most XOR cyphers in actual use are not OTPs, but [Stream Ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Cipher), such as [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4).  Those cyphers are breakable because the key is (generally) shorter than the message and the keystream is not true random but pseudo-random.  Stream ciphers can be attacked by brute force, since they do not meet the requirements for the One Time Pad.